# Django - single model with fields from multiple databases

Tags: django, database, django-models

I'm trying to create a model that will be initiated from 2 different DBs (first is MySQL, second is mongoDB).

For example:

```
class My(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.CharField() # Should relate to MySQL
    field_2 = models.CharField() # Should relate to mongoDB

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Is this possible in Django?

P.S:
I know about the Django [database routers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers), but i didn't find if it possible to mix a single model with multiple databases

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: So you are trying to make a table having columns from different database. The answer is absolutely no, but why you want to do this way?